# System.Web.HttpContext.Current (.Net Core) - Controller Type

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, httpcontext

.Net 4.8 web app has the method to get the controller type by identifying AssemblyName and then GetType on the assembly

I think I can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName for asmblyType and from it I can use split to get name.
Any suggestions how to get it with .net core

Also if there is an alternative for System.Web.HttpContext.Current in .net core?

Comment: What's the .NET Core version of your project? .NET 6?

Comment: Yes it is .Net 6